# Wordpress Multisite restict user access

Tags: multisite, users, login

I have a Wordpress Network with 3 sites. 
I want to know how can I restrict the user access in the subdomains. 
Actually, members of the principal site can login on the subdomains.

Do you know if a tiny plugin or a function can restrict users of just one single site ?

I have tried this, but still not work, or I don't know how to use it...

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

if ( ! is_user_member_of_blog() )   
    die( 'Please ask the network administrator to get access to this blog.' );
});
```

In wp-admin/network/site-users.php.

Can you help me ?

Thanks guys

Comment: please define "restrict"

Comment: Are you modifying core files?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I mean, if an user logs on site2.com, instead he is member on site1.com, the account are not defined on the site... I don't know if it's possible.
Am I clear ?

Comment: @birgire No I have tried, but it doesn't work, so I have delete this code.

Comment: just because a user is defined at site A doesn't mean he has any special access right in site B. If he does then you have done something wrong. So it is still not clear what you mean in "restrict", restrict what and when?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Ok, so you think is a plugin issue. I use Ultimate Member for my membership. 
I have tried right now to create a restricted page on site2.com who is only accessible for members (user role suscriber). 
There are no members on site2.com yet.
But with a member account (user role : subscriber) of site1.com, I can access to this restricted content for suscribers in site2.com ...

Comment: If you have a question about a specific plugin then you should ask its author. From your description it sounds like the plugin do not support wordpress network.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I tried to desactivate the plugin on both sites, and now if I want to connect a member of site1.com in site2.com I am redirected on the site1.com dashboard. Is that the basic way of Wordpress MU ?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this plugin is best for you. see 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager

You can also see the video tutorial for this plugin from this link.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Advanced+Access+Manager

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your plugin. I have developed these websites, principally, around the Ultimate Member plugin... I know I can be dumb of maintain this plugin who make me crazy, but I took lots of time to develop this site, and if I can, I hope, I don't have to change the plugin by Advanced Access Manager.